# Android 4.1.1 Renderview be hide when add view (Relativelayout)

Tags: android, surfaceview

I have a problem. when i am running my app (all android OS not bug except **Android 4.1.1**):
 SurfaceView (Renderview) can not see. And when i press sleep button from 2 to 3 times and then i can see it. I don't have solution to fix bug.

```
mRenderView = new RenderView(this);
mGridLayer = new GridLayer(this, 
                     (int) (96.0f * App.PIXEL_DENSITY), 
                     (int) (72.0f * App.PIXEL_DENSITY),
                     new GridLayoutInterface(4),
                     mRenderView
                );
mRenderView.setRootLayer(mGridLayer);  
relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.reContentMain);     
relativeLayout.addView(mRenderView);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

I don't have any solution for this problem. I hope everybody help me.